# Thymeleaf multiple resolvers required

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Currently I'm evaluating thymeleaf for one of our project below is the structure

[image]

as you can see fragments folder and the views are on the same level

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {


    return "home";
}
```

my problem I'm not able to map fragments to fragments folder

keep in mind that I dont want to use return "views\home" as a solution ,also I don't want to move fragment folder inside the views folder

I need it simple just as the resolvers detect fragments it should route to fragment folder...

I believe some is missing in my work

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  <property name="templateEngine">
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
      <property name="dialects">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect" />
        </set>
      </property>
      <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
            <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/fragments/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
            <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
            <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
            <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
          </bean>
        </set>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Note the two template resolvers, each mapped to its own path in the folder hierarchy.

Comment: I tried two template resolver solution without success , do you have sample code support your solution ?

Comment: Please post your Spring context file and the the HTML file.  For example, see [this Github project](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-jasper) from where the configuration has been taken.  The controller `org.example.web.controller.HomeController` loads the view `home.html` from `/page` folder, which in turn uses the `default.html` layout from the `/layout` folder.

Comment: I have forked and fixed your project [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/FragmentsViewsScope).  You should not have prefixed the fragment names with `fragments` since you had configured a template resolver mapped to the `fragments` folder.  Also, you should not be putting view names in the configuration file.  They will automatically be resolved by the template resolvers; after all that is what the template resolvers are for.  Run the application as `mvn clean package tomcat7:run` and then hit the home page to see it in action.

Comment: It is working like charm... I will check changes later

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible, since in order to integrate Spring MVC with Thymeleaf you had to specify `WEB-INF/home` as the root path of the views.

I know you said you don't want to move `fragments` inside `views`, but that is the most logical solution and will work perfectly.

Check out [this](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-layouts) example project where the fragments are inside the views